# Timer Reset Function Not Working!

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

## Hello Guys!

I have been trying to create a simple sample code for my newest jQuery Plugin, but it doesn't seems to be working at all! Can anyone tell where I'm going wrong?, or can anyone provide me a new function to do it. So my problem is that when I mouse over an element classed `trigger` an another element classed `eg` should `fadeIn();` but if the user takes out the mouse before the element classed `eg` fades in it should not be fading in anymore, but this is not working at all. I don't not what is getting wrong? Please help me out. (Below is my Problem HTML nad Jquery Code!)

---

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="trigger">MouseOverMe</div>
<div class="eg">See Me!</div>
```

---

**JQUERY CODE**

```
function timereset(a)
{
 var elem = $('.'+a);
 if(elem.data('delay')) { clearTimeout(elem.data('delay')); }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
   $('div.eg').hide();
    $('div.trigger').mouseover(function () {
        $('div.eg').delay(1000).fadeIn();
    }); 
    $('div.trigger').mouseout(function () {
       timereset('eg');
       $('div.eg').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

---

### THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### jQuery

```
$('.trigger').hover(function() {
    $('.eg').delay(1000).fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $('.eg').stop(true, true).hide();
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/UJBjg/1

Answer (score 2):

You don't need that `timereset` stuff, simply call `stop()` on the object and the previous effect will stop:

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Update based on the new comment:

```
$('div.trigger').mouseout(function () {
   $('div.eg').stop().hide();
});
```

Comment: Sorry But I want it not to be shown if the user takes mouse out of the element, but with your code it fading in and then fading out.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to clear the queued functions like:

```
$('div.trigger').mouseout(function () {
       $('div.eg').queue('fx', []);
       $('div.eg').fadeOut();
    });
```

Bear in mind if the fadeOut/In has already started by using stop you could end up with a semi-transparent element.

**EDIT**

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Qchqc/

Answer (score 1):

```
var timer = -1;
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('div.eg').hide();
    $('div.trigger').mouseover(function () {
        timer = window.setTimeout("$('div.eg').fadeIn(function() { timer = -1; });",1000);
    }); 
    $('div.trigger').mouseout(function () {
       if(timer != -1)
          window.clearTimeout(timer);

       $('div.eg').fadeOut();
    });
});
```